# Cannot set style of string variable

Tags: vue.js

Method:

```
getTitleText(){
      let mainTitle = "";
       let getTitle = this.titleText;
       let countGetTitle = getTitle.split(" ").length;
      if(countGetTitle > 4){
          mainTitle = getTitle.replace(/(\S+\s*){1,5}/, "$&\n");
          console.log(typeof mainTitle)
          mainTitle.style.fontSize = "30px"
        }else{
          mainTitle.style.fontSize = "40px"
        }
        return mainTitle;
    },
```

error I found
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontSize' of undefined"

found in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) with [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). A `String` has no `style` property, so `.style` would be `undefined`, leading to the error you observed for `fontSize`. But it looks like you actually want to specify the font size for the HTML element that would contain that string.

One way to solve this is to return an object with one property for the title text, and another for the font size:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    getTitleText() {
      let mainTitle = "";
      let fontSize = "";
      let getTitle = this.titleText;
      let countGetTitle = getTitle.split(" ").length;
      if(countGetTitle > 4) {
        mainTitle = getTitle.replace(/(\S+\s*){1,5}/, "$&\n");
        fontSize = "30px"
      } else {
        fontSize = "40px"
      }     
      return {
        text: mainTitle,
        fontSize,
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Then bind the result in your template:

```html
<span :style="{ fontSize: getTitleText.fontSize }">{{ getTitleText.text }}</span>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-computed-style-and-text?file=src/App.vue)